# App engine mapreduce python demo PipelineSetupError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to app engine mapreduce and want to build a web app with it.

Here are the instructions: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/3-MapReduce-for-Python

What I did is below:

1. Clone the repository.
2. `cd` into the python directory and use command `./build.sh run_demo` (which includes build_demo)
3. use chrome and go to localhost:8080

Everything goes well and I can upload the zip file.

But when I click wordcount or other two buttons, I get an 
[Internal Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpgu.png)

I tested it with another Mac, the same problem occurred. Can anybody tell me how to do with it?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Documents/AppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py",
>   line 1536, in **call**
>       rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Documents/AppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py",
>   line 1530, in **call**
>       rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Documents/AppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py",
>   line 1278, in default_dispatcher
>       return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Documents/AppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py",
>   line 1102, in **call**
>       return handler.dispatch()
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Documents/AppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py",
>   line 572, in dispatch
>       return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Documents/AppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py",
>   line 570, in dispatch
>       return method(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Gatech/Distributed/appengine-mapreduce-master/python/demo/main.py",
>   line 177, in post
>       pipeline.start()
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Gatech/Distributed/appengine-mapreduce-master/python/demo/mapreduce/pipeline_base.py",
>   line 34, in start
>       return pipeline.Pipeline.start(self, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/meteor/Gatech/Distributed/appengine-mapreduce-master/python/demo/pipeline/pipeline.py",
>   line 673, in start
>       self, idempotence_key, str(e)))
>
> PipelineSetupError: Error starting
>   main.WordCountPipeline(*(u'aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXKKAQsSDEZpbGVNZXRhZGF0YSJ4bHh5Lm1ldGVvci4uMjAxNy0wMy0xOCAyMjoxODozMy4zNTkyMDYuLmVuY29kZWRfZ3NfZmlsZTpZWEJ3WDJSbFptRjFiSFJmWW5WamEyVjBMMlpoYTJVdFZEWmZOblJZY1RSV09VOVlSMGhKY0ZCSmVIVXdVV...
>   (292 bytes), **{})#be4a9347694748cd87c7cbe0e5f14b32:

Comment: 6102? And did you ever get a solution? The same issue occurs on Archlinux. FINAL EDIT: I was able to get it working by updating all the packages relating to the google app engine api.